# Cannot register non-concrete services with WithConcreteTypeDynamicRegistrations() as rules in DryIoc

Tags: inversion-of-control, dryioc

Apparently I am trying to register an interface however, it seems like I cannot register it with non-concrete service below is an example of the implementation

```
interface IClassA
{
    void Students(List<string> students);
}

class School
{
    public School(IClassA classA)
    {
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static Rules DefaultRules => Rules.Default.WithConcreteTypeDynamicRegistrations()
                                                         .With(Made.Of(FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArguments))
                                                         .WithFuncAndLazyWithoutRegistration()
                                                         .WithTrackingDisposableTransients()
                                                         .WithoutFastExpressionCompiler()
                                                         .WithDefaultIfAlreadyRegistered(IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace)
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new Container(DefaultRules);
        //this throws
        container.Register<IClassA>();

    }
}
```

Below is the error exception:

> DryIoc.ContainerException: code: RegisteringAbstractImplementationTypeAndNoFactoryMethod; message: Registering abstract implementation type IClassA when it is should be concrete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the concrete implementation for `IClassA` interface because the container requires something concrete to instantiate.

The rule `WithConcreteTypeDynamicRegistrations` is for concrete implementation dependencies (for class and not for interface), so you don't need to register them at all. Like this:

```cs
class School
{
    public School(MyClassA classA)
    {
    }
}

public static class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new Container(DefaultRules);
        // it works even without registering School and MyClassA
        container.Register<School>();
    }
}
```